# How to change the color of a line plot in the plane?

Tags: matlab

If I plot a line in the plane as following code

```
   plot(x, y,'k-', 'linew', 1.5)
```

How to change its color?

I try

```
   plot(x, y,'-r','k-', 'linew', 1.5)
```

but this does not work...

Comment: What does the `'k-'` mean in your `plot` command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking out the `-k` (black line) will allow the new plot not to suppress the `-r` (red line). In this case MATLAB is trying to take the last colour specification given. For more plotting colours and settings: [MATLAB Documentation: LineSpec - Line style, marker, and color](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/plot.html).

```
%Arbitrary line data%
x = (0: 1: 100);
y = (0: 1: 100);

plot(x, y,'k-', 'linew', 1.5); %Black line plot indicated by -k%
plot(x, y,'-r', 'linew', 1.5); %Red line plot indicated by -r%
```

**Ran using MATLAB R2019b**